# functional type equation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f,g$ be two nonconstant positive functions on $I=[0,1]$ and we assume that :
$$
\sup_{x\in I}\sqrt{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}=\sqrt{\sup_{x\in I}f^2(x)+\sup_{x\in I}g^2(x)}
$$
This implies that $(f,g)$ are linearly dependent ?

If not what we can deduce on $f$ and $g$ ?

**Edit** : the first question is false by taking $f=1-x$and $g=1-x^2$.

Comment: If I've understood well, that would mean two functions that agree on their supreme point are linearly dependent, which doesn't quite seem true. Think about $1-x^2, 1-x$

Comment: you have right a have a more simple example now by $x$ and $x^2$ i will change the question